# Error in Vernier Scale

Tags: measurements, error-analysis

If a Vernier calliper was made with 1 main scale division equal to 1 vernier scale division could it be even used for measuring ?

Comment: Show a picture of this vernier scale please.

Comment: Just asking as a hypothetical case for deeper understanding...I don't think  such a vernier scale would even be manufactured

Comment: So, how is a vernier scale made? How does it work?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted measurement uncertainty of a marked device is half the tick mark separation. A vernier measures objects that fit within it. Anything smaller than the tick mark separation can only be reported with a size as either 0.0±0.5 or 1.0±0.5 in units of tick marks.